# Golang md5 Sum() function

Tags: hash, go, cryptography, md5, md5sum

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    hash := md5.New()
    b := []byte("test")
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash.Sum(b))
    hash.Write(b)
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash.Sum(nil))
}
```

Output:

```
*md5.digest74657374d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

Could someone please explain to me why/how do I get different result for the two print ?

Comment: Have you got the correct answer for this, I can see in comments you are not clear about the result??
I have a answer for this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm building up on the already good answers. I'm not sure if `Sum` is actually the function you want. From the [`hash.Hash`](http://golang.org/pkg/hash/#Hash) documentation:

```
// Sum appends the current hash to b and returns the resulting slice.
// It does not change the underlying hash state.
Sum(b []byte) []byte
```

This function has a dual use-case, which you seem to mix in an unfortunate way. The use-cases are:

1. Computing the hash of a single run
2. Chaining the output of several runs

In case you simply want to compute the hash of something, either use [`md5.Sum(data)`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/#Sum) or

```
digest := md5.New()
digest.Write(data)
hash := digest.Sum(nil)
```

This code will, according to the excerpt of the documentation above, append the checksum of `data` to `nil`, resulting in the checksum of `data`.

If you want to chain several blocks of hashes, the second use-case of `hash.Sum`, you can do it like this:

```
hashed := make([]byte, 0)
for hasData {
    digest.Write(data)
    hashed = digest.Sum(hashed)
}
```

This will append each iteration's hash to the already computed hashes. Probably not what you want.

So, now you should be able to see why your code is failing. If not, take this commented version of your code ([On play](http://play.golang.org/p/8yvaj7MvLB)):

```
hash := md5.New()
b := []byte("test")
fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash.Sum(b))             // gives 74657374<hash> (74657374 = "test")
fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash.Sum([]byte("AAA"))) // gives 414141<hash> (41 = 'A')
fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash.Sum(nil))           // gives <hash> as append(nil, hash) == hash

fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash.Sum(b))             // gives 74657374<hash> (74657374 = "test")
fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash.Sum([]byte("AAA"))) // gives 414141<hash> (41 = 'A')
hash.Write(b)
fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash.Sum(nil))           // gives a completely different hash since internal bytes changed due to Write()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 ways to actually get a [`md5.Sum`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/#example_New) of a byte slice :

```
func main() {
    hash := md5.New()
    b := []byte("test")
    hash.Write(b)
    fmt.Printf("way one : %x\n", hash.Sum(nil))
    fmt.Printf("way two : %x\n", md5.Sum(b))
}
```

According to http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/md5/md5.go#L88, your `hash.Sum(b)` is like calling `append(b, actual-hash-of-an-empty-md5-hash)`.

The definition of `Sum` :

```
func (d0 *digest) Sum(in []byte) []byte {
    // Make a copy of d0 so that caller can keep writing and summing.
    d := *d0
    hash := d.checkSum()
    return append(in, hash[:]...)
}
```

When you call `Sum(nil)` it returns `d.checkSum()` directly as a byte slice, however if you call `Sum([]byte)` it appends `d.checkSum()` to your input.

Comment: doesn't answer me why Sum(nil) is different

Comment: @w00d As far as I can see, the only reason why your `Sum(nil)` returns something different is that you call `Write` beforehand, which lets `hash` produce another check sum the next time `checkSum()` is called. See http://play.golang.org/p/8yvaj7MvLB

Comment: thank but the answer is still vague, since hash of an empty md5 hash does not have that number of digit.. thanks @nemo makes it clearer to me but still does not explain why the format of printed out text is different

Comment: `"%x"` prints the hex representation of a byte array, calling `Sum(b)` appends an the hash of "" to the value of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
    // Sum appends the current hash to b and returns the resulting slice.
    // It does not change the underlying hash state.
    Sum(b []byte) []byte
```

so "*74657374*d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" is actually a hex representation of "test", plus the initial state of the hash.

```
fmt.Printf("%x", []byte{"test"})
```

will result in... "74657374"!

So basically `hash.Sum(b)` is not doing what you think it does. The second statement is the right hash.

Comment: thanks it's clear to me now what Sum(b) is returning, but still unclear why Sum(nil) is different

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tell you to the point:

> why/how do I get different result for the two print ?

Ans:

```
hash := md5.New()
```

As you are creating a new instance of md5 `hash` once you call `hash.Sum(b)` it actually md5 hash for `b` as `hash` itself is empty, hence you got `74657374d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` as output.

Now in next statement `hash.Write(b)` you are writing `b` to the hash instance then calling `hash.Sum(nil)` it will calculate md5 for `b` that you just written and sum it to previous value i.e `74657374d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`

This is the reason you are getting these outputs.

For your reference look at the `Sum` API:

```
func (d0 *digest) Sum(in []byte) []byte {
85      // Make a copy of d0 so that caller can keep writing and summing.
86      d := *d0
87      hash := d.checkSum()
88      return append(in, hash[:]...)
89  }
```